# How can we play and download videos by using byte data

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have some video data in bytes:

```
AAAAIGZ0eXBpc29tAAACAGlzb21pc28yYXZjMW1wNDEAAAAIZnJlZQFAeEltZGF0AQIUGRQmM4YCwUSQhU9+Eyb7+/d..
```

When I'm trying to play and download the video by using the byte data, it's not playing the video nor downloading it

It only plays and downloads only when the data is below 5MB, but when the data is more than 5MB it stops working?

How can I resolve this issue?

```
{previewPath && <ReactPlayer
              url={`data:${mimetype};base64,${preview}`}
              controls
              width="100%"
              height="100%"
            />}
```

Comment: Not much of an answer, but you are probably running into the length limit of data urls: [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Basics_of_HTTP/Data_URLs#length_limitations).

Comment: Where are you getting the byte data from? If you can get a blob out of it (e.g. [Response#blob()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Response/blob) if it's from a `fetch()`) then you can use [URL#createObjectURL()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL/createObjectURL_static) to get a URL that references the object and you *should* be able to pass that directly to the `url` `ReactPlayer` prop